# Starting Mongod Fails Repetitively

Tags: mongodb

MacOS:

I try to get **MongoDB** running... when I type in `mongod` this is happening:

```
exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file:
/data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied
```

is this *enough* to determine what's wrong? Or should I post *the whole error message*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have the solution:

I went to the **terminal** and run `chmod 777 /data/db`.

Now `mongod` works and `mongo` works as well.